# CSS for circle avatar doesn’t work for Safari browser

Tags: css

I’m using gatsby react template for my blog but when I’m opening it on Safari browser (iPhone or Mac) the avatar image is not circle.
[easy-code.blog](https://easy-code.blog)

This is the style I used for the avatar

```
.bio-avatar {
  margin-right: var(--spacing-4);
  margin-bottom: var(--spacing-0);
  min-width: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: This is not a `React` question, there is no React code.

Answer (score 2):

You should change your CSS code with this one. The issue is that the `border-radius` value.

```
.bio-avatar {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: The real issue is because his element doesn't have any height.